# Can I use s3manager to rename a large file or small file on s3?

Tags: go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-go

This code works great when data is an `io.Reader`:

`s3manager.UploadInput{
    Bucket: aws.String("MyBucket"),
    Key:    aws.String("file1.mov"),
    Body:   data,
  }`

The s3 manager:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/tree/master/service/s3/s3manager

knows how to upload a 4MB file or a 14GB file with Multipart upload. i.e. the 4MB can NOT use multipart because it's too small.

So s3manager is great for this. I don't have to worry about the size.

But can I use s3manager also for renaming a file already on s3? The rename will do a new Multipart upload behind the scenes because the 14GB one is too big to copy without Multipart.

(s3 has no rename feature, renames are copy then delete)

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: ah, https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/745 explains